# How to make a custom Pop Up Dialogue reuseable

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

So I created a custom Pop Up dialogue box in UWP, to make it reusable, i made use it of a User Control

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ContentDialogueBox.PopUpCustomDialogueUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ContentDialogueBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


    <ContentDialog  x:Name="MyContentDialogCustom"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Title="Lorem Ipsum"
                    PrimaryButtonText="OKxxx"

                    SecondaryButtonText="Canc"
                     Margin="0,0,-98,0" Width="1000" >
        <Grid Background="Wheat">


            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="First Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Middle Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="Middle Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="First Name" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>



        </Grid>
    </ContentDialog>
</UserControl>
```

I was able to reference the user control in another page that contains the button named ButtonShowContentDialog4, what i want to achieve is display the PopUp Dialogue box, when i click the button in the page. Please how do i achieve this.

```
private void ButtonShowContentDialog4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      //show the PopUp here when this button is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve that. Apart from the thing that you could have made a custom *ContentDialog* instead of putting it inside the user control, you can probably achieve your goal like this:

In your *PopUpCustomDialogueUserControl* class define a method that would show your popup:

```cs
public async Task ShowMyDialog() => await MyContentDialogCustom.ShowAsync();
```

Once you have it, add your *PopUpCustomDialogueUserControl* somwhere in your *Page* in xaml (remember to have a suitable namespace added (*ContentDialogueBox*) defined below as *local*) and add it a *Name*:

```xml
<local:PopUpCustomDialogueUserControl x:Name="MyCustomDialog"/>
```

Then you can call its method in code:

```cs
private async void ButtonShowContentDialog4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyCustomDialog.ShowMyDialog();
}
```

Comment: when i tried ur solution, the pop up was not visible on the screen

Comment: @OsamuyimenOsagiedeDennis I'm not sure what you have done, but when I copy-pasted your code it seems to work with the above.

Comment: ok,i would check properly and give feed back, thank u so much for your time

Comment: please did you try your solution in universal windows app(UWP)?

Comment: @OsamuyimenOsagiedeDennis Yes, definitely UWP. Have you been able to build your code? Have you debuged it? Can you share a sample showing what you are trying?

Comment: i imported the name space in the click button page using
`    xmlns:uc="using:App1"`
Then i added page resources using
`  <Page.Resources>
        <uc:MyUserControl1 x:Name="MyCustomDialog"/>
    </Page.Resources>
`
In the code behind for the click button page, i implemented the function below

  `private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await MyCustomDialog.ShowMyDialog();
        }`

i am trying to paste all my code in the comment, but it too long, i hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: @OsamuyimenOsagiedeDennis Just don't add it to resources, but directly to a page content. Accessing it via resources would need different code, but in this case there is no difference it's in content/resources.